# Regex to grab word before a certain character in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to extract word before a certain character from the names column and append new colum as color

if there is no color before the name then I want to display empty string

I've been trying to extract the word before the match. For example, I have the following table:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data = ['red apple','green topaz','black grapes','white grapes']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Names']) 

     Names
red apple
green apple
black grapes
white grapes
normal apples
red apple
```

The below code i was treid
**I am geeting Partial getting output**

```
df['Names'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall(r'(\w+)\s+apple', x)))

df['Names'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall(r'(\w+)\s+apple|grapes', x)))
```

Desired output:

```
Names           color
red apple       red
green apple     green
black grapes    black
white grapes    white
normal apples
red apple       red
```

Please help out me this issue

Comment: `df['color']=df['Names'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall(r'(\w+)\s+apple|grapes', x)))`

`          Names  color`
`0     red apple    red`
`1   green apple  green`
`2  black grapes `      
`3  white grapes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is just to remove the *fruit* names to get the color:

```py
def remove_fruit_name(description):
    return re.sub(r"apple|grapes", "", description)

df['Colors'] = df['Names'].apply(remove_fruit_name)
```

If you have many lines it may be faster to compile your regexp:

```py
fruit_pattern = re.compile(r"apple|grapes")

def remove_fruit_name(description):
    return fruit_pattern.sub("", description)
```

Another solution is to use a *lookahead assertion*, it's (probably) a bit faster, but the code is a bit more complex:

```py
# That may be useful to have a set of fruits:
valid_fruit_names = {"apple", "grapes"}
any_fruit_pattern = '|'.join(valid_fruit_names)

fruit_pattern = re.compile(f"(\w*)\s*(?={any_fruit_pattern})")

def remove_fruit_name(description):
    match = fruit_pattern.search(description)
    if match:
        return match.groups()[0]
    return description

df['Colors'] = df['Names'].apply(remove_fruit_name)
```

Here is an example of lookahead quoted from the documentation:

> `(?=...)`
>
> Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a *lookahead assertion*. For example, `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.

Finally, if you want to make a difference between `normal` and `green` you'll need a dictionary of valid colors. Same goes for fruit names if you have non-fruit strings in your input, such as `topaz`.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution:
gives me a color_column like ['red', 'green', 'black', 'white', '']

```
import re
data = ['red apple','green topaz','black grapes','white grapes','apples']

colors_column = list(map(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall(r'(\S\w+)\s+\w+', x)) ,data))
```

Comment: how to apply df

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily an elegant trick, but this seems to work:

```
((re.search('(\w*) (apple|grape)',a)) or ['',''])[1]
```

Briefly, you search for the first word before apple or grape, but if there is no match, it returns `None` which is false. So you use or with a list of empty strings, but since you want to take the first element of the matched expression (index 1), I used a two element list of empty strings (to take the second element there).